# How do I copy and paste strings of codes on a text editor on BASH environment

Tags: mcedit

Currently working on a BASH SCRIPT, how do i copy and  paste a string of code?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for, also not well versed in BASH, but seems like you are looking for a loop. [Here](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php) is a tutorial on how to go about using Loops in BASH.